Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate
I can't figure out why I keep getting this error of Livewire:

Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the [database-list] component.
Ensure that the [name, id, data] of the Livewire component wasn't tampered with between requests.

I already searched a lot and none of the answers seems to work for me.
I'm using Laravel and Statamic and I'm trying to create a component that filters the entries from fieldset group by taxonomy tags.
This is my component:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Livewire\Component;
use Statamic\Facades\Entry;

class DatabaseList extends Component
{
    protected $databaseSet = [];
    protected $uniqueTags = [];
    protected $filteredSet = [];
    public $taxonomyTag = null;
    public $q;

    public function mount($databaseSet, $q = null)
    {
        // Map and initialize databaseSet
        $this->databaseSet = collect($databaseSet)->map(function ($item) {
            $image = $item['image'];
            $entry = Entry::find($item['entry']->id());
            return [
                'id' => $entry ? $entry->id() : null,
                'title' => $entry ? $entry->title : null,
                'image' => $image,
                'tags' => $entry ? (array) $entry->get('articles_tags', []) : [],
                'date' => $entry ? $entry->date : null,
            ];
        })->toArray();

        $this->q = $q;

        // Collect unique tags
        $this->uniqueTags = collect($this->databaseSet)
            ->pluck('tags')
            ->flatten()
            ->unique()
            ->values()
            ->toArray();

        $this->filteredSet = $this->databaseSet;

        Log::info('Database set initialized: ' . json_encode($this->databaseSet));
    }

    public function render()
    {
        // Filtering logic based on selected taxonomyTag
        if (!empty($this->taxonomyTag)) {
            Log::info('Filtering by tag: ' . $this->taxonomyTag);
            $this->filteredSet = collect($this->databaseSet)->filter(function ($item) {
                return in_array($this->taxonomyTag, $item['tags']);
            })->values()->toArray();

            Log::info('Filtered set: ' . json_encode($this->filteredSet));
        } else {
            // If no tag is selected, show all data
            $this->filteredSet = $this->databaseSet;
        }

        return view('livewire.database-list', [
            'databaseSet' => $this->filteredSet,
            'uniqueTags' => $this->uniqueTags,
        ]);
    }

    public function filterByTag($tag)
    {
        // Set the selected tag for filtering
        $this->taxonomyTag = $tag;

        Log::info('Tag selected: ' . $tag);
    }

    public function resetFilter()
    {
        // Reset the filter, showing all items
        $this->taxonomyTag = null;
        $this->filteredSet = $this->databaseSet;

        Log::info('Filter reset, showing all items.');
    }
}



this is my database-list.antlers.html
<div>
    <section class="section-database-news-list">
        <div class="filter-list-navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between filter-list-header">
                        <div class="filter-list-title">Categories</div>
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end filter-list-search">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end search">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..."/>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="icon">
                                {{ partial:components/svg/_search }}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                    <div class="filter-list-categories">
                        <ul class="d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
                            <li class="d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="resetFilter()" class="">All</a>
                            </li>

                            {{ uniqueTags }}
                            <li class="d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="filterByTag('{{ value }}')" class="">{{ value }}</a>
                            </li>
                            {{ /uniqueTags }}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                {{ databaseSet }}
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                    {{ partial:components/cards/_database-list-card }}
                </div>
                {{ /databaseSet }}
            </div>
            {{if databaseSet.length > 6}}
                <div class="d-flex align-items-start align-items-md-center justify-content-center load-more-wrapper">
                    <a href="#"
                       class="d-inline-flex justify-content-between align-items-center custom-btn-icon type-02 size-01 height-01 load-more">
                        <span>Load More</span>
                        {{ partial:components/svg/_circle-more }}
                    </a>
                </div>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </section>
</div>


and for helping to understand, this is the structure of my database_list.yaml:
title: 'Database - News'
fields:
  -
    handle: database_set
    field:
      collapse: false
      previews: true
      fullscreen: true
      sets:
        db_item:
          display: List Item
          fields:
            -
              handle: image
              field:
                max_files: 1
                mode: list
                container: images
                restrict: false
                allow_uploads: true
                show_filename: true
                show_set_alt: true
                type: assets
                display: Image
                listable: hidden
                instructions_position: above
                visibility: visible
                replicator_preview: true
                hide_display: false
            -
              handle: entry
              field:
                max_items: 1
                mode: select
                create: true
                collections:
                  - articles
                display: Entry
                type: entries
                icon: entries
                listable: hidden
                instructions_position: above
                visibility: visible
      type: replicator
      display: 'Database Set'
      listable: hidden
      instructions_position: above
      visibility: visible
      replicator_preview: true
      hide_display: false
      localizable: true


